# How can I get a Wix CustomAction to print a custom error message if it fails?

Tags: wix

How can I get a Wix CustomAction to print a specific error message of my choosing if it fails (rather than a generic error message)?

```
<CustomAction Id="XXX" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="SomeCommand" Return="check" Execute="deferred"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little confusing because you have an exe custom action, so why can't the program display its actual error message? If the exe doesn't do that, it's not easy to get a meaningful message beyond "the exe failed" unless the exe has a number of exit codes that tell you exactly what happened. So your message is just going to be " failed" with little other information.

If this is your code, and you want to provide a specific error message that describes the error exactly, I'd encourage use of a Dll call, either C/C++ or managed code C# with DTF. Then you can use the Win32 API MsiProcessMessage() and equivalents such as session.message in the C#/DTF world. It has the advantages of knowing when it's a silent install (and not displaying anything), ensuring the message goes on top of the current dialog (probably a progress dialog) and putting the message in the MSI log if you are creating one. All of this obviously assumes that your code is thorough enough to say exactly what failed and why, so that the error message is meaningful.

Comment: The exe currently is command line (no UI). I suppose I could wrap it with some UI, though I would rather not. The exe either works or fails (crashes). I would like it to say "XXX failed" if the exe custom action fails (rather than something generic such as "One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup...")

Comment: The exe can be a Windows program instead of a console program - it doesn't need to show UI, and that means it could show an actual error message dialog (instead of a console window?) if it fails. The alternative would be to write a Dll-type custom action that calls the exe and displays you error when it fails, but if it were me I'd put the effort into making the program more friendly. Anyway, all that is if you don't want to put the program code into a custom action Dll.

Comment: Specifically use session.Message(InstallMessage.Error, new Record("some message");

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new custom action what does whatever you need it to do. That includes, running your command(s) and logging exactly the bits and pieces what you want, with your own format.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx - Creating WiX custom action.